# Salesforce Matrix report help

Tags: reporting

[image]

Can anyone help me here, how I can build this complex report. I would like to show the record count for each picklist field based on picklist value.

Regards,
Ajay

Comment: is it correct that the 5 labels at the top are 5 different picklist fields on 1 object? And each picklist has the same 3 options?

Comment: @Guy: Yes, you are right. each field has 5 options in actual scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible in your current datamodel. Each record will have 5 picklists filled in. Those picklists can't be separated and reorganized into different reporting groups.

The only way to do this would be to generate child records under your object containing 3 fields:

1. parentRecord (master-detail)
2. picklist type
3. picklist value (same as the current picklist values)

This object you will be able to put in a matrix report with the picklist type at the top and the picklist value at the left

But the real challenge is to actually get data into there. I roughly see 3 options for that:

1. replace the current picklists by the child records and have the end users create child records instead of filling the current picklists
2. same as #1, but instead of having the end users create the child records build a VisualForce frontend that looks like 5 picklists on the parent record but actually generates the child data in the background.
3. keep the current picklists, but in the background generate and maintain the child records

Each of these varies in complexity and usability. The question is: do you want to go that far just to be able to generate your report?

Comment: :), Thanks for your reply. I am trying to avoid going to that level of customization. As it is not only one report there are multiple reports to be created on different filters. Anyway, we are sure that, it is not possible with standard reporting.

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry, can't make it any nicer :-)